# Model Missing, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, models

I am using and have been using the framework CodeIgniter for a while. It works perfectly on my localhost, once I upload it to a server it gives the following error message

> > Unable to locate the model you have specified: auth_model

To point it out, it works on my apache perfectly, do you have any idea to what the problem can be? I am talking with customer support of the webbhotel, but they can't seem to find anything on their end.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It manages to load many different files, the session library, my own controllers, helpers and view files. It just models that it stops at, I've named them all 'Auth_model.php", 'Login_model.php' etc. The models themselves are declared class Auth_model extends CI_Model {}

Comment: The server might be case sensitive. Did you try renaming the model to `auth_model`? Please post the file structure of your site and the definition of the auth_model

Comment: The file structure is as standard for codeigniter as it can be I think. System, Application are two seperate folders, within Application there is config, controllers, core, models etc.

I tried the rename all to small letters yesterday, I can give it a go again.

Comment: Did you try logging the value of `BASEPATH` to make sure it's correct?

Comment: Okay, I've checked the value of BASEPATH, how do I know it that is correct or wrong though? It looks correct to me. Comparing it to my localhost BASEPATH it does not however, on my localhost it is C:/.../system/ on the webhotel it is /customers/.../httpd.www/system/ as I am using sessions, I also got errors that the sessions can't be initalized because of header information sent (I just echoed the BASEPATH), so codeigniter finds the session libraries at least.

Comment: Before putting your file `auth_model` into server can you tell me what was your name of the file I mean to say it was in upper case or in lower case?

Comment: The file was named Auth_model.php

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a path issue,

I would first check where your starting at and get some data to compare with

- CodeIgniter FCPATH and APPATH are both set in the main index.php file,

  - FCPATH = root
  - APPATH = application folder

Find out what your paths are set to, check your config/config.php file make sure you have correct info there.

Just a thought, are you using a common auth library? Sucb as freak/ion/bit/etc auth's

The session error, is being caused by echoing data you can google the error and get a decent understanding of the error from there.

Comment: They seem to be set correct, specially since it manages to load every other files but the models. I am using a home made auth model, it works perfectly on my localhost. And lastly, the session errors I know, the reason I pointed out is that it manages to find the session library. If it wouldn't have posted the errors that would've meant some pathing is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the webhotel (one.com) got a delay when you upload, hence it was a bit troublesome to actually troubleshoot it, but here it goes. Every file name except for the exception of MY_Controller needs to be in lower cases. So the answer was pointed out by some people.

The problem is with codeigniter because it looks for lower cases only in some cases. So yeah, models should be in lower cases from now on!